# Docker exec with config file outside of container

Tags: docker

I have Docker container on my host and I want run script inside docker container with `docker exec`

```
docker exec MyContainerID python /home/myuser/my/path/my_script.py --key1=value1 --key2=value2
```

How can I add config file from the outside of docker container?
Is it possible do with one row command line like this command:

```
docker exec MyContainerID python /home/myuser/my/path/my_script --key1=value1 --key2=value2 --config=/my/path/outside/container/my_config.cfg
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget that docker is about process isolation, but you can copy a file from outside the container, then

`docker exec command_with_this_file`

as an example, extract from

http://hub.docker.com/r/k3ck3c/captvty/

first a copy a zip file

`docker cp 9087050696d4:/home/gg/Captvty/Vidéos/ ~`

then extract this zip file inside the container

`docker exec -it container_id unzip -d ~/Captvty ~/Téléchargements/captvty-2.3.10.zip`

and reply

`Yes to All`

Comment: Thank you for the answer but this is not what I asking for.
I know that i can copy file before script execution but i want copy file at the moment of script execution.

Comment: the container is isolated, so you can either use `ADD` or `COPY` in your Dockerfile, so at build time the required file will be copied, and can be executed in the `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` directive, or use `docker cp` and then `docker exec -it comand_using_your copied_file`

Comment: Maybe what you are looking fr is `docker cp... ; docker exec...`

Comment: I already use `docker cp` and i want to do stuff like this in one expression.

Comment: You do 2 differents things, so apart from my last comment, you may use nvm on some port, but it will be more complicated

Comment: Not nvm but nc (netcat) sorry for the typo

Comment: see what you can do with netcat https://github.com/chilcano/docker-netcat but I doubt it wil me simpler that `docker cp ...; docker exec...`